# Cursor not being updated in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

I have a WinForms application with a user control in which I change the cursor dynamically based on its location. I create my custom cursors as static members of the user control, like this:

```
private static Cursor _openHandCursor = new Cursor( Properties.Resources.openHand.Handle );
```

Then in the `OnMouseMove` override I set the appropriate cursor, like this:

```
this.Cursor = <some condition> ? _openHandCursor : Cursors.Default;
```

When I start the application, it works correctly. However, after a couple of cursor changes (around 20) it sticks with the default (arrow) bitmap and does not change any more. But the oddest thing is that after this happens, I check the `Handle` property of the current `Cursor` value and it is equal to the handle of the `_openHandCursor` object! So it seems the value of the property is still being set correctly but the cursor bitmap on the screen doesn't get updated. Any suggestions about this weird behaviour?

Comment: Something mysterious about this code.  A cursor gets embedded as a byte[] in the resources, not anything that would have a Handle property.  Are you editing the Resources.Designer.cs file by hand?

Comment: @HansPassant See my comment to @max's answer - the resources I used originally was an `Icon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
private static Cursor _openHandCursor = new Cursor( Properties.Resources.openHand.Handle );
```

to

```
private static Cursor _openHandCursor = Properties.Resources.openHand;
```

When you create `Cursor` object (`new Cursor (<Handle>)`), it just reuses the same handle as cursor from resources.
Since you don't store reference to original cursor (created by `Properties.Resources.openHand.Handle` property getter), it is going to be garbage collected.
`Cursor` class defines finalizer, which destroys handle by calling `DestroyCursor()`, making it invalid. Now `Cursor`, which you created, has the same handle, but it does not know that handle is not valid anymore.
OS just uses default cursor when you try to set an invalid one.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. The resource I was using in the `Cursor` constructor was originally an `Icon` which was obviously not correct. I changed it so that there is now a proper `.cur` file (in a `byte[]` form) which is then used in the `Cursor` constructor overload taking a `System.IO.MemoryStream` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the cursor in the `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events of the UserControls.

Psuedo Code:

`MouseEnter Event`

`Change mouse cursor to hand`

`MouseLeave Event`

`Change mouse cursor to normal`

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx)